# How to fix SQL Server 2019 connection error due to certificate issue

Tags: sql-server, connection, certificate

I am using a .NET console app to test SQL Server 2019 database connection and get following error message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

The user id and password are valid. The C# code is not using any encryption. I have not configured any certificate in SQL Server configuration.

1. Is certificate required in SQL Server 2019?
2. Can I get a self generated cert from the SQL Server?
3. If no self-generated cert available, where can I get a valid certificate for free?

Comment: _I have not configured any certificate in SQL configuration._ Oh, but you have. SQL Server gets installed with a Self-Signed X.509 certificate which you'll be able to find in Manage Computer Certificates > Personal. In your connection string either set `Encrypt=false;` to use an unencrypted connection, or `TrustServerCertificate=true;` to accept the self-signed cert. Or, if you're so inclined, create a new certificate from your organization's CA and install it via [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/manage-certificates).

Comment: 1. The issue has been resolved by creating self-signed certification using "Certificate" snap-in in MS Management Console /mmc.  Following YouTube video provides detailed instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7ONeACYBdE

 2. When connecting to SQL DB in a program, the connection string should include **TrustServerCertificate=True**. Otherwise, the same error related to certificate will occur.

Comment: `TrustServerCertificate=True` is effectively saying "I couldn't care less", you may as well do `Encrypt=false` for all the difference it would make, at least you gain a little performance by not encrypting. Ideally you should have a proper signed certificate, and your client machine needs to trust the CA that signed that certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me this did the trick

- In Visual Studio, open the Server Explorer pane.
- Right-click on the data connection (database) and select "Modify connection".
- Check the box for "Trust Server Certificate".

[image: Modify connection - trust server certificate]

Note: this may not be advisable in a production environment, but I was just testing a local non-prod app so it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 29):

To improve the answer, let me sum up the comments:

While setting `TrustServerCertificate=True` or `Encrypt=false` in the connection string is a quick fix, the recommended way of solving this issue is to provide a proper certificate for your SQL Server from a trusted CA.

To install a certificate for a single SQL Server instance ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/manage-certificates)):

1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the console pane, expand SQL
   Server Network Configuration.
2. Right-click Protocols for *<instance Name>*, and then select Properties.
3. Choose the Certificate tab, and then select Import.
4. Select Browse and then select the certificate file.
5. Select Next to validate the certificate. If there are no errors, select Next to import the certificate to the local instance.

Comment: But for step 4, where do we get the certificate file from?

Comment: You have to create one by a CA (certificate authority) that is trusted by the client. For example you could use DigiCert, LetsEncrypt or an internal CA. There's a whole process necessary, here is a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898

Comment: Just want to make the point that if you're doing mickey mouse coding on your own PC (e.g. LOCALDB), don't worry about sourcing certs. TrustServerCertificate=True or Encrypt=false will be fine. Of course, don't ever do this with work databases!

Answer (score 6):

In your appsettings.json file add `TrustServerCertificate=True` to your connection string i.e
`"ConnectionStrings": { "Default":"Server=servername;Database=Dbname;TrustServerCertificate=True" }`