# How to create SQL Server login for IIS AppplicationPool ,When server has join a domain group

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

My ASP.NET Core MVC web app is completed and shows no error, but when I try to deploy using an IIS profile to my web server, I get this error in the event log:

> The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

I'm successful creating a SQL Server login for Apppool but can't connect to the database

Comment: This ist probably a duplicate of [this so-question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75662560/3825869). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: You should make sure you have trusted the sql server's certificate or use the `TrustServerCertificate=True`.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a sql connection problem.

you can try these:

- The connection string in appsettings.json may be incorrect.
- If you are trying to reach a remote computer, you need to allow remote connections