Connection between Visual Studio and MySQL database
I'm one ear in self learning C# and Unity. Currently I'm in casual development of game. I want to store data in database. I have latest version of Visual Studio and MySQL Server Management Studio.
I succesfuly connected my local DB to VS. I'm able to create tables and add parameters manualy, but I'm not able to comunicate with DB via code itself. The code (below) compile without issue. It seems that I have an error in my connectionString, but I triplececked it.
Can you kick me in the right direction?

using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

public class SQLConnector
{
    public static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        string connectionString =
            "Data Source=BaddyPC;" +
            "Initial Catalog=dbname;" +
            "User id=AnyBaddy;" +
            "Password=userpassword;";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}

I tryed to create multiple diferent users with different permisions.
I tryed to re/create multiple servers.
I tryed Postgresql instead of SSMS.
After certificate issue i tryed suggestion from comments: How to fix SQL Server 2019 connection error due to certificate issue
Still have the certificate problem.
Added "Encrypt=False" into connection string as @Alexander Petrov said in deleted coment. Connection successful! Thank you wery much, guys!

MSsql and MYsql are two different databases

Your screenshot shows MS SqlServer, not MySql. ssms is Sql Server Management Studio. So you are using the wrong classes and namespace

Thanks for noticink, you are right.
Changed:
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; -> using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
MySqlConnection  -> SqlConnection
Got error in cmd:
Error: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The chain of certificates starts with an untrusted authority.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399243/how-to-fix-sql-server-2019-connection-error-due-to-certificate-issue

I've removed the SSMS tag as it's clearly not relevant here. As for the RDBMS you are actually using, that's somewhat unclear as you reference 3 in the post, have a screenshot of SQL Server but are using libraries for MySQL..

You didn't specify the password for AnyBaddy in the connection string, did you?

Added "Encrypt=False" into connection string as @Alexander Petrov said in deleted coment. Connection successful! Thank you wery much, guys!
